# $SO_{3}\cong P^3$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Here is a discussion of $SO_{3}\cong P^3$ in Basic topology,Armstrong,Page 77.
I think $\mathbb H$ below is the space of quaternions.

- We think of $S^3$ as the quaternions of norm 1,and note that conjugation in $\mathbb H$ by a nonzero quaternion always induces a rotation of the three-dimensional subspace of pure quaternions.This defines a function $\mathbb H-\{0\}\to SO_3$ which is in fact a homomorphism,onto,and continuous......

Well,I can follow except continuity.I don't think it is obvious at all,since $SO_3$ is a subspace of $\mathbb E^9$ while $\mathbb H$ is 4-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Think of $SO_3$ as a subspace of $Map(S^3,S^3)$. Then the adjoint of $\mathbb{H}\setminus\{0\}\rightarrow SO_3$ is the map $(\mathbb{H}\setminus\{0\})\times S^3\rightarrow \mathbb{H}$ which is the restriction of the continuos adjoint action of $\mathbb{H}$ on itself.

Comment: @Tyrone What is $Map(S^3,S^3)$ and adjoint?Sorry,but I'm new in topology.

Comment: $Map(S^3,S^3)$ is the space of maps $S^3\rightarrow S^3$ given the compact open topology. The adjoint of a map $f:X\times Y\rightarrow Z$ is the map $\tilde{f}:X\rightarrow Map(Y,Z)$ defined by $\tilde{f}(x)(y)=f(x,y)$ (and vice-versa). I'm sorry if my comment wasn't particularly useful to you.